# React Native WebView Loading Error Handling

Tags: android, reactjs, webview, react-native

When the webview loads an invalid url, which property should I set to display an error view? I try renderError, it triggers the console message but did not display the view.

here's the code:

```
<View style={styles.webview_body}>
  <WebView
   source={{uri:this.props.url}}
   onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
   renderError={this.loadError.bind(this)}
 />
</View>

//the fucntion which display the error message
loadError(){
console.log('loaded');
return (
  <View>
    <Text>
    something goes wrong.
    </Text>
  </View>
)
}
```

here's the screenshots

[image]

**[Update]** As I reload to clear the error, there's a temporary state which display the error view.

[image]

Comment: should we handle the onError also?

Comment: I'm not sure which properties are required.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `onError` prop as shown below to render a view after an error and also try handling the different WebView errors. `renderError` can be used to render a view that shows when resolving the WebView errors

```
onError = (e) => {
    let uri = new URI(this.props.url);
    let host = uri.host();
    let insecureHosts = [-1004, -6, -1202]; //all error codes as displayed on your console 
        if(e){
            //Handles NSURLErrorDomain in iOS and net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Android
            if(insecureHosts.indexOf(e.nativeEvent.code) !== -1){
                this.setState({url: `http://${host}`});
            }
            //Handles Name resolution errors by redirecting to Google
            else if(e.nativeEvent.code === -1003 ||  e.nativeEvent.code === -2){
                this.setState({url: `https://www.google.com/#q=${host}`});
            }
        } else {
        //loads the error view only after the resolving of the above errors has failed
            return(<View>
                    <Text>Error occurred while loading the page.</Text>
                  </View>);
            }
};
renderError = (e) => {
    //Renders this view while resolving the error 
    return(<View>
                <ActivityIndicator
                    animating={ true }
                    color='#84888d'
                    size='large'
                    hidesWhenStopped={true}
                    style={{alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', padding:30, flex: 1}}/>
            </View>);
};
```

Remember to install [urijs](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) and import it so as to make use of `URI`.